# lithium framework how to make a query with OR

Tags: php, mysql, lithium

I start work with lithium PHP framework. I have to make a query to get questions which have '%test%' or '%easy%' in 'title' field.
I've tried to do it using following code:

```
$questions = Questions::find('all', array(
        'conditions'    => array(
            'name' => array(
                'like' => array(
                    '%easy%',
                    '%test%'
                )
            )
        )
    ));
```

but it makes this query:

```
SELECT * FROM `questions` AS `Questions` WHERE (`name` LIKE '%easy%' AND `name` LIKE '%test%')
```

how to replace AND with OR?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as a solution to your question you can use in (=) instead of like

```
'conditions'    => array(
    'name' => array(
        '=' => array(
            '%easy%',
            '%test%'
        )
    )
)
```

this will generate the query:

```
WHERE ((`name` IN ('%easy%', '%test%')))
```

Or can be used when searching using two different fields:

```
'conditions' => array(
    'OR' => array(
        'name' => array(
            '=' => array(
                '%easy%',
                '%test%'
            )
        ),
        'name2' => array(
            '!=' => array(
                '%easy%',
                '%test%'
            )
        )
    )
),
```

And this will generate query:

```
WHERE ((`name` IN ('%easy%', '%test%')) OR (`name2` IN ('%easy%', '%test%')))
```